# Prolog: failing statement executes twice

Tags: prolog

I'm a beginner in Prolog (using SWI-Prolog) and I have the following problem:

I have a rule defined as follows:

```
start:-
   write("Enter first list: "), read_list(List1), 
   write("Enter second list: "), read_list(List2), 
   equal_length(List1, List2), 
   compare(List1, List2, Alike),
   write(" The lists are "), write(Alike).

start:- write("The lists should have the same length!!").
```

This is how I read the lists:

```
read_list([H|T]):- read(H), H\=[], read_list(T).
read_list([]).
```

Compare is a set of rules that will compare the list, but it never gets to execute, I've even replaced it for this:

```
compare(_, _, "the same").
```

This is how equal_length looks like:

```
equal_length([_|T1], [_|T2]):- equal_length(T1, T2).
equal_length([], []).
```

So it fails when the lists don't have the same length.
The problem is, when start fails, it executes the first occurrence again (with List1 and List2 already bound)!

I have tried simpler stuff like this:

```
hi:- 1>2, write("Nonsense").
hi:- write("Of course it doesn't work").
```

And the output is the second string. 
Why the first one doesn't behave like that?

**Edit:**

After further testing I found out that this strange behavior only happens when reading lists from that custom method, and only when more than one list is read.

Comment: what `do/0` is supposed to do ?

Comment: @CapelliC that part never gets to execute, but added it for clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is the lack of management of backtracking. When your statement fails, Prolog will try to get new values for the lists that will satisfy `equal_length`. 
Here is an example that handles backtracking with the `!` operator:

```
start:-
      read_list_data( List1, List2 ),
      equal_length(List1, List2),
      compare2(List1, List2, Alike),
      write( List1 ), nl,
      write(" The lists are "),
      write(Alike).

start:- write("The lists should have the same length!!").

read_list([H|T]):- read(H),
      H\=[],
      read_list(T).
read_list([]).

compare2(_, _, 'the same').

equal_length([_|T1], [_|T2]):- equal_length(T1, T2).
equal_length([], []).

read_list_data( List1, List2 ) :-
      write("Enter first list: "),
      read_list(List1),
      write("Enter second list: "),
      read_list(List2),
      !.
```

**Explaination:**

The `!` mark avoids the backtrack undesired behavior by letting Prolog know that it has to commit to the choices it made so far (namely, keep the values of the lists).
I found a good source of information on this [here](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse43), where backtracking is explained with tree diagrams.

Comment: It works. Absolutely. Can you explain what was it doing and why the ! stops that?

Comment: When backtracking, it is not executed before cut(!).It is one of the functions of Prolog.